# Facebook API limit on Graph /picture call without access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there an API limit on the amount of calls to graph.facebook.com/{facebookid}/picture an application or IP can make without an access token?  If so what kind of limit is it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Facebook Rate Limits, Restrictions and Disables

Why is my app getting rate limited?
To optimize the performance of our APIs and the apps that call them, we rate limit apps that make unoptimized queries, request data too frequently or generate a high number of requests without an access token. This minimizes the possibility for one app to negatively affect performance for other apps.

Facebook offers a tool for developers to better understand if they are being throttled and the reasons. To access this tool, click the Statistics link from the Developer app and click the Throttling tab.

All production apps should sign their requests with an access token, application secret, or session secret. Learn more about signing calls using an OAuth 2.0 access token or older authentication methods.

https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=100502990045478

Comment: Thanks for the Facebook rate limits information.  I was hoping for a little more concrete (such as a number of requests per time period) but this may have to suffice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about limits, limit your API calls:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/picture?ids=FBID1,FBID2,...FBIDn&redirect=false
```

You'll get a json object back with the IDs and picture urls for each of the ids.

Comment: Thanks for the information about making the multiple picture calls into one.  Definitely something I'll look into.  Thanks!